# Frame sizing of tableview within nested child controllers/subviews

Tags: ios

I'm a bit confused by the proper frame sizing of a table view to fit within my screen.

Here's my setup of view controllers within view controllers:

- UITabBarController
- - UINavigationController as one of the tab bar viewcontrollers; title bar hidden
- - - ViewController - a container view controller because I need the option to place some controls beneath the UITableView, sometimes (but not in the current scenario)
- - - - UITableViewController

Now, my question is what the proper frame dimensions of the UITableview should be. Here's what I've got in the ViewController viewDidLoad method. I used subtracted 49.0 (the size of the tab bar) from 480.0. However, this leaves a black bar at the bottom. 20.0 appears to do it (coincidentally?) the size of the status bar, but I don't understand why that would be. Wouldn't the true pixel dimensions of the tableview be 480-49?

```
// MessageTableViewController is my subclass of UITableViewController
MessagesTableViewController *vcMessagesTable = [[MessagesTableViewController alloc] init];
CGRect tableViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 480.0 - 49.0);
[[vcMessagesTable view] setFrame:tableViewFrame];
self.tableViewController = vcMessagesTable;
[self addChildViewController:vcMessagesTable];

[[self view] addSubview:vcMessagesTable.view];
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem also -- I think it would be best not to hard code the size but to refer to the size of one its ancestor controllers. In this case, the UINavigationController, that's the direct child of the tabBar controller should have the right frame to fill the whole screen minus the tabBar. So I would subtract (if you need to) from that frame height if you want space at the bottom, otherwise, just use that frame. I think that self.navigationController finds the nearest nav controller above your controller of interest.